# Getting an error on vb: missing semicolon (;) at end of sql statement

Tags: sql, vb.net

I have this piece of code with a Try & Catch:

```vb
Try
    comando = New OleDbCommand("INSERT INTO login VALUES (Usuario, Password, Cuenta)" & Chr(13) &
        "VALUES(UsuarioText, PasswordText, TipoText)", conexion)
    comando.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Usuario", UsuarioText.Text)
    comando.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Password", PasswordText.Text)
    comando.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Cuenta", TipoText.Text)

    comando.ExecuteNonQuery()
    MsgBox("El registro ha sido guardado exitosamente", MsgBoxStyle.Information, "Informacion")


Catch ex As Exception
    MsgBox("El registro no se pudo guardar", MsgBoxStyle.Critical, "Informacion")
    MsgBox(ex.Message)
End Try
```

I am trying to fix the error by putting some `;` at the end of the statements but still not working.

What could it be?

Comment: A wild guess, I never worked in vb: `comando = New OleDbCommand("INSERT INTO login VALUES (Usuario, Password, Cuenta)" & Chr(13) &
                                    "VALUES(UsuarioText, PasswordText, TipoText);", conexion)` Can you try this change?

Comment: change "VALUES(UsuarioText, PasswordText, TipoText)" to "VALUES(@UsuarioText, @PasswordText, @TipoText)" and make the parameter names match what is in the string.

Comment: I agree with @Steephen. Also, when posting SQL related questions, it's a good idea to include the database platform you're targeting. SQL Server, for instance, doesn't tend to care about the `;` character, but Oracle is pretty particular about it. Not sure about other platforms, because those are the two I use most.

Comment: what is this for  & Chr(13) &. you know insert statement works as INSERT (columns) VALUES(VALUES)

Comment: A) PASSWORD is a reserved word in access so escape it [Password] or dont use reserved words as column names B) that `Chr(13)` is likely to cause trouble C) never ever store passwords as plain text - hash them.

Comment: @Steephen I've tried it and still getting the same error.

Comment: @NietzscheProgrammer try all the suggestions here and add additional information if you find a question in comments

Answer (score 0):

Try this Approach

```vb
' SQL COMMAND FOR INSERTING VALUES 
Dim objCommand As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand()
objCommand.Connection = conexion

objCommand.CommandText = "INSERT INTO login VALUES ([Usuario], [Password], [Cuenta])" & _
    "VALUES(@Usuario, @Password, @cuenta)"

' CONTROLS BINDING
objCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Usuario", UsuarioText.Text)
objCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Password", PasswordText.Text)
objCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Cuenta", TipoText.Text)

'OPEN CONNECTION
conexion.Open()
'EXECUTE CONNECTION
objCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
MsgBox("El registro ha sido guardado exitosamente", MsgBoxStyle.Information, "Informacion")

'CLOSE CONNECTION 
conexion.Close()
```

I commented every section of the code

Hope it helps

That is simple approach I use for my project

this is incorrect `VALUES(UsuarioText, PasswordText, TipoText)`
correct one `VALUES(@Usuario, @Password, @cuenta)` because I use parameters.addWithValue to bind the controls

```
objCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Usuario", UsuarioText.Text)
objCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Password", PasswordText.Text)
objCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Cuenta", TipoText.Text)
```

Answer (score 0):

Hey @NietzscheProgrammer

Try adjusting the `INSERT` statement, so it is only one line. Remove the CHAR(13) and also adding the "@" symbol in the variables. Do not forget to place the SEMICOLON at the end of the statement.

```vb
Try
    comando = New OleDbCommand("INSERT INTO login VALUES (Usuario, Password, Cuenta) VALUES(@UsuarioText, @PasswordText, @TipoText);", conexion)
    comando.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Usuario", UsuarioText.Text)
    comando.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Password", PasswordText.Text)
    comando.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Cuenta", TipoText.Text)

    comando.ExecuteNonQuery()
    MsgBox("El registro ha sido guardado exitosamente", MsgBoxStyle.Information, "Informacion")

Catch ex As Exception
    MsgBox("El registro no se pudo guardar", MsgBoxStyle.Critical, "Informacion")
    MsgBox(ex.Message)
End Try
```

Comment: I am yet getting the same error eve with this approach.

Answer (score 0):

Omit the `VALUES` after your table `Login`
it should be:

```
 comando = New OleDbCommand("INSERT INTO login (Usuario, Password, Cuenta) VALUES (UsuarioText, PasswordText, TipoText)", conexion)
```

**EDIT:**

Also: put "@"

```
"VALUES (@UsuarioText, @PasswordText, @TipoText)", conexion)
```

Make Sure that the values with @ is match in the `comando.Parameters`
change it to:

```
comando.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UsuarioText", UsuarioText.Text)
comando.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PasswordText", PasswordText.Text)
comando.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TipoText", TipoText.Text)
```